# No operator matches the given name and argument type. You might need to add an explicit type cast

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core

Cant run my query I have a "Id" on my db of "users" this is type "uuid" of postgres, I have a GUID id on dot net core and I want get thee user with the same id, and return this user.

```
    public async Task<T> GetById(Guid entity)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            var result = await this.connection.QueryFirstAsync(askForId, entity);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Entity has a value of:

```
entity: {675d83ca-c7b6-4efe-bf98-46a48e8a28fd}
```

My query is this:

```
private readonly string askForId = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id = @Id";
```

How can give a solution to this:

```
 "ClassName": "Npgsql.PostgresException",
    "Message": "External component has thrown an exception.",
    "Data": {
        "Severity": "ERROR",
        "InvariantSeverity": "ERROR",
        "SqlState": "42883",
        "MessageText": "operator does not exist: @ uuid",
        "Hint": "No operator matches the given name and argument type. You might need to add an explicit type cast.",
        "Position": 32,
        "File": "parse_oper.c",
        "Line": "731",
        "Routine": "op_error"
    },
}
```

Comment: Don't know any C# or .net but it looks like you're assuming that `@Id` will be a placeholder but Npgsql probably expects PostgreSQL-style numbered placeholders (i.e. `$1`, `$2`, ...). The error message suggests that PostgreSQL is interpreting the `@` as an operator and the `Id` as an identifier (i.e. the `Id` column which is a UUID). So read the Npgsql docs and see what sort of placeholders you should be using.

Comment: I don't think that this is his problem @mu_is_too_short.  I don't have a solution for him but here is a core 3.x Npgsql query that I am using `"SELECT DG.id, DG.name FROM DEVICE_GROUP DG WHERE DG.id = @id";` and it works fine.  After calling a new NpgsqlCommand() I use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id)`  I myself gave up on his same UUID problem and converted to a string (I didn't need performance) so I can't answer this.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas-ReinstateMonica I got half of it right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change my query just the @Id to @id:

```
private readonly string askForId = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Id = @id";
```

and change to `QueryFirstAsync` to  `QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync` becuase I need know if dont find nothing.

```
public async Task<T> GetById(Guid entity)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                var result = await this.connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(askForId, new { id = entity});
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

And change the `entity` to new `{ id = entity}` and work fine the query